# Git for windows stops working after "verify bundle" inside a process

Tags: c#, .net, windows, git, cmd

Using .NET4 on Microsoft Visual Studio 2015

I have a function to validate bundle files. The Git command is running inside a process, like so:

```
public VerifyBundle(String bundlePath, String repositoryPath){
  Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(repositoryPath);
            Process p = new Process
            {
                //set process configuration
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    FileName = "cmd.exe",
                    RedirectStandardInput = true,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    WorkingDirectory = path,
                    Arguments = "/C git bundle verify " + bundlePath,
                    WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
                }
            };
            p.Start();

            string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Whenever the .bundle file is not valid, right after the p.Start, Git stops, and opens a popup saying: "Git for windows stopped working".
Why is it breaking GIT during the process? What can I do to intercept this error and avoid disrupting my application during run time?

EDIT: Running the command manually on Git Bash against the same file outputs
`Segmentation Error`

Comment: Does issuing that git command manually through a command prompt work fine? That is, when running against a bundle file that isn't valid, does it crash horribly or does it simply output an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug with the mingw version of [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win), it does not happen with [Cygwin's](https://www.cygwin.com/) version.

If possible use Cygwin's version although it's an earlier version of git as it does not have this issue.